# Fatal error when using standard function puts

Tags: c++

IDE: Visual Studio Community 2022

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    puts("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

The above returns an error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The error message doesn't match the shown code. Please make sure it's a proper [mre], and then copy-paste the full and complete build output into the question.

Comment: Also, even is you use "C" functions, the shown program is C++ so you should tag only that language.

Comment: Looks like visual studio is broken, maybe create a new project, if that doesn't work reinstall visual studio

Comment: Unrelated: It should be `std::puts("Hello, World!");`

Comment: @TedLyngmo It didn't work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo same problem. I will reinstall it.

Comment: It's not unusual for `<cstdio>` to `#include <stdio.h>`.     But the cause of your error message is probably a broken installation of your compiler (or Visual Studio, in your case). Try reinstalling.   Also check environment variables, as some of them affect how VS works (e.g. affects what directory it searches for headers).   If those attempts fail, the problem may be because (currently) VS2022 is a preview version - and such versions are not necessarily complete.

Comment: @Mohammad Yes, my comment wasn't about the problem you face. "_Unrelated:_" is often used to comment on unrelated issues.

Comment: @Peter. Yeah I figured as much. I installed the 2022 version but when I reverted back to the 2019 version it worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure that you installed all the required components during visual studio installation? Did you install C++ for Deaktop application?

Comment: @MarcoBeninca I did yes. I have never encountered a broken installation before. This is a first. The suspicious thing is that <cstudio> includes stdio header. Which I tried to find out if it does it. I am not fully familiar of how directives are processed here and if the include statement has cases where it includes other header files.